How can I query 2 SqlLite tables with a join and multiple where statements
I'm trying to write an SQLite query that would return a row, that would execute the following statement:
Select all messages, where the Action.action is receive, and Action.name is john.  Also if message_id is not null, show Action.name as sender_name where message_id is the same
Output Results



message
name
sender_name




Hello World!
john
dave


Anonymous Message
john
<null>




Action Table



id
message_id
action
name




1
1
send
dave


2
1
receive
john


3
<null> 
send
dave


4
2
receive
john



Message Table



id
message




1
Hello World!


2
Anonymous Message



I'm also using Sqlalchemy so if there is an even easier way to achieve this, please let me know.
Could anyone shed any light on how to achieve this please?

You should perform a left join on the 'action' table, separating the main select (receive) from the join (send, since the latter can be null). Then, just add the remaining criteria of your query.
SELECT message.message, receive.name, send.name FROM action AS receive 
LEFT JOIN action AS send ON send.action = 'send' AND send.message_id = receive.message_id 
JOIN message ON message.id = receive.message_id
WHERE receive.action = 'receive' AND receive.name = 'john';

Result:
message         name    name
-------------------------------

Hello World!    john    dave
Annon Message   john    <null>


@MooingDuck how would you achieve this with 1 join?

Oh, I see now. Each result is joining two rows in the Action table. My mistake, I misunderstood the task.
It can still be done with only a single join, but it requires a group by, so that's more complex, not simpler.
